# Update rows in Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update data in MySQL DB but it is throwing error:

```
UPDATE scrapedDataTable  SET productDesc=, 
                            moreProductImages=full/545521_1363869251%20copy-500x500.jpg,full/545521_1363869251%20copy-275x275.jpg,full/545522_1363869309%20copy-500x500.jpg,full/545522_1363869309%20copy-74x74.jpg, ,productCategory=Clothing, 
                            productSubCategory=NA  WHERE Server=http://1click1call.com/Jeans-Shirts-Tshirts-Trousers/W-for-Woman-Kurta-54552


And error:
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'moreProductImages=full/545521_1363869251%20copy-500x500.jpg,full/545521_13638692' at line 1")
"(<class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>)"
```

My table structure is:

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| productTitle       | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| productSite        | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| productDesc        | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| productURL         | varchar(325)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| productMRP         | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| productPrice       | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| productCategory    | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| productSubCategory | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| imageURL           | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| moreProductImages  | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

query :

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE scrapedDataTable  SET productDesc=%s,moreProductImages='%s', ,productCategory=%s, productSubCategory=%s  WHERE productURL=%s" %(productDesc,image_paths,productCategory,productSubCategory,productURL))
```

Can anybody help me please...

Comment: Looks like you are missing quotes, around all your string literals

Comment: If i remove % before values list i am getting this error : `'str' object is not callable
"'str' object is not callable (<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL should be:

```
UPDATE scrapedDataTable  SET productDesc='', 
                            moreProductImages='full/545521_1363869251%20copy-500x500.jpg,full/545521_1363869251%20copy-275x275.jpg,full/545522_1363869309%20copy-500x500.jpg,full/545522_1363869309%20copy-74x74.jpg, ',productCategory='Clothing', 
                            productSubCategory='NA'  WHERE Server='http://1click1call.com/Jeans-Shirts-Tshirts-Trousers/W-for-Woman-Kurta-54552'
```

And wait. Your Primary Key is a long URL string ? Really ? It's better to use a short key such as an integer to keep your table well indexed.

**UPDATE AFTER QUESTION UPDATE:** The line should be:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE scrapedDataTable  SET productDesc='%s',moreProductImages='%s', ,productCategory='%s', productSubCategory='%s'  WHERE productURL='%s'" %(productDesc,image_paths,productCategory,productSubCategory,productURL))
```

Comment: Please first look at the question i know quotes are missing and i did not do that intentionally i am simply replacing value of variable ...Look again at question i have edited ....

Comment: Answer is updated. That's why input is required to be sanitized before adding into query. The answer is still valid & can help your issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how do i escape `'s` because if i use '%s' then it only takes string upto ' of 's and ignore rest....

Comment: Not sure which MySQL library you're using, but in general, there is a function called `mysqli_real_escape_string` (for MySQLi) to escape the input. Check your MySQL library.

Comment: -1 for being bad practice. The Python database API, implemented by all Python SQL libraries, uses paramaterized queries - none of this manual escaping of arguments nonsense that is common in PHP. You need to scrap the single quotes around the `%s`s in the query, and rather than manually (and injection-vulnerably) formatting the parameters into the query with the `%` operator, replace that `%` with a comma `,` to have the parameters passed as a second argument to `execute()`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip...And Shivan Raptor for your help...

Comment: Made the change suggested by you( Mark Amery ) and worked like a charm...Thanks ...